# using select with like to check letter

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I don't know how I can use SELECT with `LIKE` in SQL so I can print the "name of some persons" which have one single `r` in the middle of their name. 
For example, Maria has `r` in the middle of the name.

I tried, `LIKE '%r%'` but it also shows the names with r at final.

Answer (score 2):

Try this `Where` clause

```
Where col NOT LIKE '%r' -- to filter names ending with r
  AND col NOT LIKE 'r%' -- to filter names starting with r
  AND length(REPLACE(col,'r','')) = length(col) - 1 -- to make sure only one r exist
```

Comment: How can i make sure i also show the col only with one r at the middle.

Comment: Prdp has done that for you.....
Loosely translated.....

WHERE col has r in the middle
AND col DOES NOT have r at the end
AND col DOES NOT have r at the start

Comment: Yes but if i have something like "Marria" it's not ok.

Comment: @JohnK - Updated check now

Comment: This could be simplified (and save execution time) by removing the first condition, as it is already guaranteed by the last condition.

Comment: @mathguy - Agreed.. Updated

Answer (score 2):

The solution below finds all strings that have exactly one occurrence of lower-case 'r', which is not in the first or the last position.

```
... where regexp_like(col, '^[^r]+r[^r]+$')
```

Explanation: The `^` at the very beginning means "start at the beginning of the input string" (otherwise the search could begin anywhere), and similarly the `$` at the end means "anchor to the end of the input string". `[^r]` means any single character OTHER THAN `r` (the caret operator `^` within a matching set `[...]`), and `+` means one or more occurrences. So this guarantees beginning of string followed by at least one non-r character followed by exactly one r followed by at least one non-r followed by the end of the string. Exactly what you wanted.